# Present Perfect Tenses

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

> I have been in Europe for 2 years

Does this sentence mean I was in Europe for 2 years?

What's the difference between these two sentences?

> I have been in Europe

Can this mean I am still in in Europe?

Comment: In addition to Jay's answer have a look at [this general explanation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present-perfect-simple-i-have-worked?q=Present+perfect+simple+%28I+have+worked%29) on usage of present perfect simple at CDO

Answer (score 2):

This is a subtle one caused by the context.

"I have been in Europe for two years" would normally be understood to mean that you travelled to Europe two years ago and have remained there.

Note that very similar wording could be used to mean that you were in Europe during some specific event, but are not necessarily still there. Like, "I have been in Europe for two national elections." I went there during one, then I went there during another. But I might well have left in between and/or after the second.

"I have been in Europe" could mean that you visited Europe at some time in the past. "What continents have you visited?" "I have been in Europe. And I have been in Africa." In that case it does not imply that you are still there. It can also mean that you have been there for an unspecified period of time and are still there. "Why didn't you attend the meeting last Thursday?" "I couldn't make it. I have been in Europe."

Comment: Your 'exceptions' in para 4 ought to use 'to Europe' not 'in Europe', except the last, which would be far less confusing & far more accurate to say 'I was in... '

Comment: @Tetsujin: No, Jay is right. In context, it's valid, and illustrative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it sounds wrong to me, except for emphasis…  'You were never in Europe!' 'Yes, I *have* been in Europe'. Push it further, 'I went to Europe', never 'I went in Europe'. It feels equivalent to me - though, I always have to admit, I'm no grammarian.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't say, "I went in Europe". But "I have been to Europe" and "I have been in Europe" seem basically equivalent to me.

Comment: Jay, I think there's a detectable nuance of difference - you'd usually say *...been **to** Europe* because the fact of *travelling **to**, visiting* Europe is likely to be your focus *(I **did** that)*. But when explaining why didn't attend a recent meeting, what matters is that you weren't around - you were ***in** Europe* (*I **was** there* for some/all of the relevant timeframe).